# Accessing the SPAM folder

Tags: php, yahoo, pop3, spam, hotmail

I'm in the process of writing a basic PHP email client. So far I've written a basic POP3 class using fsockopen. It works great so far however I'm noticing a big limitation. The POP3 protocol doesn't have support for folders, which means I can't access the SPAM folder. How do hotmail and yahoo's clients access the SPAM folder? Do they store it on a different non-POP3 server?

I find the SPAM folder is important to include in the client as some undeserving emails end up there.

Comment: The web clients don't access the mailboxes via POP at all; they have access to them directly. The only real solution is to completely turn off filtering on the server and do junk mail filtering within your client. Or use real email services with IMAP.

Comment: "don't access the mailboxes via POP at all" - some might not use POP, but direct filesystem access to mails access is very rare IME - and where it is implemented it is based on maildirs not mailboxes.

Answer (score 1):

POP3 doesn't have a concept of folders. It's there to access what amounts to your Inbox only. For folders, you need to use IMAP.